# Definite Integral Ruining My Life

Tags: definite-integrals

So I need to prove that any function that fulfills Equation 1 also fulfills Equation 2 for an arbitrary small value of $k.$

Equation 1:
$f'(x)=k\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+1-k}$

Equation 2:
$f(n+1)-f(n)=k\frac{f(n)}{f(n)+1-k}$

What I have tried:
I have been trying to integrate Equation 1 with a definite integral from $n$ to $n + 1$ and I'm currently stuck trying to figure out what the integral of $\frac{1}{f(x)+1}$ is.

Can someone let me know if I'm on the right track and what the integral of $\frac{1}{f(x)+1}$ is??

Thanks guys!

Comment: $$ \frac{df}{dx} = k \frac{f}{f+1-k} $$ $$ \frac{(f+1-k) \,df} f = dx $$ $$ \left( 1 + \frac{1-k} f \right) df = dx $$ etc.

Comment: maybe try the mean value theorem? You can't integrate $f$ without knowing what it is, but the left hand side of the second equation is a difference quotient for $f$.

Comment: This is all the information I was given for the problem (not hw, don't worry). I have no $f(x)$ given. How do I prove this problem though? I know I cannot use any direct proofs or induction so I don't know what this problem wants as far as proving it.

Comment: This separation of variables readily gives you $x$ as a function of $f,$ but the inverse of that seems not as clearcut. However, it is not yet clear to me that one must solve this differential equation in order to answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I need to prove that for $n\leq x\lt n+1$, why $f(x)=f(n)$ and integrate $f'(x)=k_\frac{f(n)}{f(n)+1-k}$ from $n$ to $n+1$, with the right side as a constant.